# Статическая маршрутизация Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, сеть, static, route, windows-server

[image: Схема]

Имеется схема, компы - 2 компьютера на Windows 10
и S - это Windows Server 2019
На сервере нужно поднять статическую маршрутизацию через роль Удаленный доступ(см картинку)[image: Схема 2]

Проблема в следующем: Комп A видит до 192.168.2.1, Комп B до 192.168.1.1
сервер видит все адреса
Как настроить статическую маршрутизацию чтобы компы видели друг друга

Comment: посмотреть таблицы маршрутизации на каждом хосте можно командой **route print**

Comment: Решилось переустановкой роли Удаленный доступ-Маршрутизация. Сама подхватила адреса и без настроек маршрутизации всё заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось переустановкой роли Удаленный доступ-Маршрутизация. Сама подхватила адреса и без настроек маршрутизации всё заработало